# content provider custom client - no content is recieved

Tags: android, provider

I have read many answers regarding content providers, but I can't understand why my client isn't recieving any data stored in the database.

-I'm using the same uri everywhere.

-I have added the read and write permissions in my provider in the manifest.

-I have exported the provider and set the multiprocess to "true" too.

-My client in app has the same read and write permissions.

-I created a jar containing the resolver for my client in app. I have added it as a library.

-I know that the parameters got into the database because I can see all the info inside the database.

-My client wasn't able to connect to the provider until I have done all mentioned above, because I fixed exception regarding it.

Now everything should work and doesn't crash any more, but all the strings I get from the resolver are empty. I don't know if it really conects to the provider or if something else is incorrect.
Please help me!
Q: Do the permission string and the authorities string in the provider declaration have to match the package structure?

Here are some pieces of code:
Provider declaration in manifest:

```
    <provider
    android:name=".lessons.LessonsProvider"
    android:authorities="com.scheduler.lessons"
    android:readPermission="com.lessons.READ_DATABASE"
    android:writePermission="com.lessons.WRITE_DATABASE"
    android:multiprocess="true"
    android:exported="true" />
```

Resolver code:
    public class LessonsResolver {

```
private static final String TAG = "LessonProvider";

private final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.scheduler.lessons";
private Uri uri;
private Context mContext;

public LessonsResolver(Context context) {
    super();
    mContext = context;
    uri = Uri.parse("content://"+ PROVIDER_NAME+"/parameters_table");
}
public String getString(String parameterName, String defaultValue) {
    Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, "parameter_name='"+parameterName+"'", null, null);
    if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        Log.e(TAG,"getString: for parameterName: " + parameterName + ", cursor from the content provider  "+ (cursor == null ? "is NULL" : "is empty" ));
        cursor.close();
        return defaultValue;
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String s = cursor.getString(2);
    cursor.close();
    return s;

}
```

Permissions in client app manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.lessons.READ_DATABASE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.lessons.WRITE_DATABASE"/>
```

My provider:

```
public class LessonsProvider extends ContentProvider {

public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.scheduler.lessons";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "lessons";
private static final String TAG = "LessonsProvider";
private static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+PROVIDER_NAME + "/parameters_table");
...
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder sqlBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    sqlBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
    Cursor c = sqlBuilder.query(mSqlDB, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    return c;       
}
```

Comment: so where is your content provider?

Comment: tried to call `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor` inside `getString`?

Comment: no. I didn't understand what to add and where? in the getString resolver or in the query function in the provider?

Comment: inside `getString()` method

Comment: first, thanks for this tool. the cursor is empty

Comment: in `mContext.getContentResolver().query` see `String selection` and `String[] selectionArgs` arguments, now your `selectionArgs` is null, also what does `TABLE_NAME` look like?

Comment: selectionArgs is null because my database is very simple, only a parameter and its value. selection is used

Comment: so pass `null` for testing as 'selection` parameter and dump the cursor again,  what do you see?

Comment: the cursor is still empty. it seems like it doesn't realy connect to the provider

Comment: so dump the cursor in `LessonsProvider#query`